# How can I create aurora cluster db instance in different available zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I created a Aurora cluster (postgresql 11) with 3 instances in ap-southeast-2 region (1 writer, 2 reader). I noticed that the writer is in the AZ `2b` but two readers are in the same AZ which is `2a`. How can I make them evenly spread to 3 AZ?

The cloudformation for this cluster:

```
AuroraDBFirstInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceClass: ${self:custom.postgresqlInstanceClass}
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineVersion: ${self:custom.postgresqlEngineVersion}
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref AuroraDBCluster
      PubliclyAccessible: ${self:custom.publiclyAccessible}

  AuroraDBSecondInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceClass: ${self:custom.postgresqlInstanceClass}
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineVersion: ${self:custom.postgresqlEngineVersion}
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref AuroraDBCluster
      PubliclyAccessible: ${self:custom.publiclyAccessible}

  AuroraDBThirdInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceClass: ${self:custom.postgresqlInstanceClass}
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineVersion: ${self:custom.postgresqlEngineVersion}
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref AuroraDBCluster
      PubliclyAccessible: ${self:custom.publiclyAccessible}
```

[image]

Comment: have you created them manually?

Comment: I created them via cloudformation `AWS::RDS::DBInstance`.

Comment: What is your `AuroraDBCluster` ?

Comment: you can specify the az at in the cloudformation template as well if you don't aws pick randomaly from the subnet group you specify in your case it is default subnet group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the AZ in cloudformation it self. If you do not specify subnet then Aurora will pick random AZ from subnet group you provide.

```yaml
Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
Properties: 
  AllocatedStorage: String
  AllowMajorVersionUpgrade: Boolean
  AssociatedRoles: 
    - DBInstanceRole
  AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: Boolean
  AvailabilityZone: String
  BackupRetentionPeriod: Integer
  CACertificateIdentifier: String
  CharacterSetName: String
  CopyTagsToSnapshot: Boolean
  DBClusterIdentifier: String
  DBInstanceClass: String
  DBInstanceIdentifier: String
  DBName: String
  DBParameterGroupName: String
  DBSecurityGroups: 
    - String
  DBSnapshotIdentifier: String
  DBSubnetGroupName: String
  DeleteAutomatedBackups: Boolean
  DeletionProtection: Boolean
  Domain: String
  DomainIAMRoleName: String
  EnableCloudwatchLogsExports: 
    - String
  EnableIAMDatabaseAuthentication: Boolean
  EnablePerformanceInsights: Boolean
  Engine: String
  EngineVersion: String
  Iops: Integer
  KmsKeyId: String
  LicenseModel: String
  MasterUsername: String
  MasterUserPassword: String
  MaxAllocatedStorage: Integer
  MonitoringInterval: Integer
  MonitoringRoleArn: String
  MultiAZ: Boolean
  OptionGroupName: String
  PerformanceInsightsKMSKeyId: String
  PerformanceInsightsRetentionPeriod: Integer
  Port: String
  PreferredBackupWindow: String
  PreferredMaintenanceWindow: String
  ProcessorFeatures: 
    - ProcessorFeature
  PromotionTier: Integer
  PubliclyAccessible: Boolean
  SourceDBInstanceIdentifier: String
  SourceRegion: String
  StorageEncrypted: Boolean
  StorageType: String
  Tags: 
    - Tag
  Timezone: String
  UseDefaultProcessorFeatures: Boolean
  VPCSecurityGroups: 
    - String
```

for better info for each properties you can refer to cloudformation template documention. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html

Answer (score 0):

You can control placement of your db instances through [DBSubnetGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbsubnet-group.html) and [AvailabilityZone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-availabilityzone).

Below is **working** example for creating `DBSubnetGroup` consisting of 3 subnets in 3 different AZs in `us-east-1`. The only thing you need to do to run this example is to **change subnet-ids** to your own from `us-east-1a`, `us-east-1b`,`us-east-1c` AZs in `MyDBSubnetGroup`:

```
Resources:

  MyDBSubnetGroup: 
    Properties: 
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: Subent Group in 3 AZs
      SubnetIds: 
        - subnet-82c876e5
        - subnet-21ef547d
        - subnet-a9e16487
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"

  RDSCluster: 
    Properties: 
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref MyDBSubnetGroup
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      MasterUserPassword: postgresql22332   
      MasterUsername: postgresql
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBCluster"

  RDSDBInstance1: 
    Properties: 
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      DBClusterIdentifier: 
        Ref: RDSCluster
      DBInstanceClass: db.t3.medium
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      PubliclyAccessible: "true"
      DeleteAutomatedBackups: true
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"

  RDSDBInstance2: 
    Properties: 
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1b
      DBClusterIdentifier: 
        Ref: RDSCluster
      DBInstanceClass: db.t3.medium
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      PubliclyAccessible: "true"
      DeleteAutomatedBackups: true
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"

  RDSDBInstance3: 
    Properties: 
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1c
      DBClusterIdentifier: 
        Ref: RDSCluster
      DBInstanceClass: db.t3.medium
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      PubliclyAccessible: "true"      
      DeleteAutomatedBackups: true      
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
```